# Jquery ui dialog buttons click function issue and effects another dialog on the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add buttons dynamically to dialog, so i had used below script.

```
$("a", that.element).each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass("hide")) {
                    target = this;
                    //Adds the new button to the existing list of buttons.
                    buttons.push({ text: this.text, click: function () { that._addClass(menu, target); } });
                    //Gives the new list of buttons to the dialog to display.
                    menu.dialog("option", "buttons", buttons);
                }
            });
```

So, buttons were added the problem is on the click event when ever or what ever button i click it hits the function, but the target is remained unchanged as the last buttons anchor(means as i am creating buttons out of anchors in the loop it is caching and passing me the last iteration value all the time).

Another issue is that I had another dialog somewhere in the page, even that dialog is displaying these buttons...

Any work around to handle these issue's please..................

Comment: please, provide a working fiddle with your code (html/css/js) -> www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

`Another issue is that I had another dialog somewhere in the page, even that dialog is displaying these buttons...`

For this part, check the classes or Ids you are passing to the function. It may happen that the other div also contains those classes.

Comment: I had to separate files that do js stuff for the two dialogs, by the time of initialization of dialogs i am caching them in a variable and using that to get things done. I guess it won't conflict with each other...

Answer (score 0):

Just add a var to your target variable and it will work. Please also see http://jsfiddle.net/xf77k/ i made a simple example since i don't have all your surrounding code that you're using. `that` and `menu` and `buttons` are missing.

```
$("a", that.element).each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("hide")) {
            var target = this;
            //Adds the new button to the existing list of buttons.
            buttons.push({ text: target.text, click: function () { that._addClass(menu, target); } });
            //Gives the new list of buttons to the dialog to display.
            menu.dialog("option", "buttons", buttons);
    }
});
```

Comment: Its not working, even though if it works it's not healthy to have an self executable function in loop...

Comment: I edited the answer the main problem, why you're getting always the same result is that the variable has been global. Please see the jsfiddle. You just have to adopt it to your sussounding code.